Eclipse, remove duplicate "Maven Project Builder" entries
How can I remove the duplicate "Maven Project Builder" entries that are shows in Eclipse -> Builders? (The remove Button is greyed out when highlighting either entry)
*I have added them by clicking the project -> Maven -> "Update Project ..."


Maybe look in the .project file in the project root directory to see what the buildSpec build commands are.

Thanks for the tip, I can remove it there.

Thanks to @greg-449 for pointing out the .project file where I can manually remove the dupes

